# How can I use SharpSVN in my own Mono (c#) project?

Tags: c#, mono, sharpsvn

I would like to use the SharpSVN library to access SVN API, how can I access the SharpSVN namespace from my code? I downloaded the library, it doesn't seem to be code files, but some DLLs, some .exe/.xml.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt you will be able to use SharpSVN as a cross-platform library given its dependency on the Visual C++ runtime per http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/

It will of course work on Mono on Windows, but that's probably not what you're after.

Comment: Based on this blog post, even MonoDevelop uses different SVN bindings on Windows and other OSs, http://foodformonkeys.blogspot.com/2009/06/monodevelop-installer-for-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Mono IDE, you should be able to reference dlls and other .net assemblies to your project.  I believe SharpSvn is coded in .NET 2.0 which is supported by Mono. So you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

As any other library, you add it as a refference, and then access it using either a using statement, or a the fully qualified name.

See MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx